# How to write bind functions in point-free style?

Tags: haskell

I often find myself having to explicitly specify `return` to wrap an expression in `IO/Maybe/Either`, etc... but I'm sure there must be a better way to make it point-free.

For example:

`countLines :: FilePath -> IO Int
 countLines file = readFile file >>= countLines
     where countLines = (\d -> return $ (length . lines) d)`

Is there a way to achieve a point-free style for the `countLines` function? Writing lambdas for each step of the `>>=` is tiresome.

Comment: Just to check my understanding: is it legal to have the inner countLines function have the same name as the outer one?

Comment: @AndrewJaffe I didn't notice that at first. It is legal, but a bad practice for readability issues, IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
countLines :: FilePath -> IO Int
countLines file = readFile file >>= countLines
     where countLines = (\d -> return $ (length . lines) d)
```

By the way, it is not a good practice to use the same name of the function in a `where` clause: the function looks recursive even if it is not.

Back to the question, the code above means

```
countLines file = readFile file >>= (\d -> return $ (length . lines) d)
```

which means

```
countLines file = readFile file >>= (return . (length . lines))
```

which can be written as

```
countLines file = length . lines <$> readFile file
-- or
countLines file = fmap (length . lines) $ readFile file
```

One can go further and also remove the `file` point, but readability would be slightly harmed.

```
countLines = fmap (length . lines) . readFile
```

> Is there a way to achieve a point-free style for the countLines
>   function? Writing lambdas for each step of the >>= is tiresome.

Well, pointfree style is hardly more readable in the general case. Why don't you use do notation instead?

```
countLines :: FilePath -> IO Int
countLines file = do
   d <- readFile file
   return . length . lines $ d
```

This is not as elegant as the pointfree-ish variant in this case, but is much more general. Even when chaining many `>>=`s sometimes the following style is used:

```
foo =
  m1 >>= \x1 ->
  m2 >>= \x2 ->
  m3 >>= \x3 ->
  ...
  mN >>= \xN ->
  return (...)
```

Comment: I'm inclined to avoid the `do` notation, as it looks too much like an imperative style of programming. Is this a valid sentiment? As well, it seems as though `do` is syntactic sugar for `>>=` anyway, and so unless it significantly improves readability (which I remain open-minded to in certain cases) I'd rather avoid it until I understand Haskell better.

Comment: `do` notation actually is just syntactic sugar for `>>=`. In my opinion, there is no reason to avoid imperative style in Haskell when it makes the code easier to read. Sequential computations are most naturally stated in a sequential manner. Doing sequential computation in a referentially transparent way is monad's raison d'etre.

Comment: @Wildhoney It can be beneficial at the beginning to avoid do notation so to have a solid grasp on what's underneath. But I believe that when one gets familiar with Haskell no longer associates do with imperative style, unless the monad at hand is an IO-related or a stateful one. Even if applicative style has become more common now, do notation is still quite idiomatic.

Answer (score 9):

To make your function here

```
countLines :: FilePath -> IO Int
countLines file = readFile file >>= countLines
 where countLines = (\d -> return $ (length . lines) d)
```

pointfree, we need to first refactor it to this:

```
countLines :: FilePath -> IO Int
countLines file = readFile file >>= countLines
 where countLines = (\d -> return $ (length . lines) $ d)
```

Now, we can compose the return with the other functions, like so (we can remove the parenthesis):

```
countLines :: FilePath -> IO Int
countLines file = readFile file >>= countLines
 where countLines = (\d -> return . length . lines $ d)
```

Now we can take out the point (again, remove parenthesis):

```
countLines :: FilePath -> IO Int
countLines file = readFile file >>= countLines
 where countLines = return . length . lines
```

Now the function can be inlined:

```
countLines :: FilePath -> IO Int
countLines file = readFile file >>= return . length . lines
```

As an added bonus, if you want to make countLines totally pointfree, you can use the Kleisi composition operator (found in `Control.Monad`) instead of bind, like so:

```
countLines :: FilePath -> IO Int
countLines = readFile >=> return . length . lines
```

although it is arguable that the other version is more readable.

The last one can also be written like:

```
countLines :: FilePath -> IO Int
countLines = return . length . lines <=< readLine
```

which has the advantage that you can read the function from right to left and see exactly how the function "flows".

Comment: You could flip the final form to `return .  length . lines <=< readFile`.

Comment: Yeah, that could work as the flow of the code would be to the same direction. Added a note.

Comment: `countLines = (return $ (length . lines))` is not equivalent to `countLines = (\d -> return $ (length . lines) d)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code

```
countLines file = readFile file >>= countLines
  where countLines = (\d -> return $ (length . lines) d)
```

contains the anonymous function

```
\d -> return $ (length . lines) d
```

which is equivalent to

```
\d -> return ((length . lines) d)
```

and the point `d` can be removed using function composition to give

```
return . (length . lines)
```

This allows you to write

```
countLines :: FilePath -> IO Int
countLines file = readFile file >>= return . (length . lines)
```

The pattern `a >>= return . f` is equivalent to `fmap f a`, so you can also write

```
countLines :: FilePath -> IO Int
countLines file = fmap (length . lines) (readFile file)
```

and you can now remove the point `file` using function composition as well,

```
countLines :: FilePath -> IO Int
countLines = fmap (length . lines) . readFile
```

Personally I find this more readable than the original, but opinions may differ.

Comment: Is it not common practice in Haskell to define named functions in the `where` clause to impart a clearer intent upon the function you're defining? For example, you've refactored my code to inline the lambda, which for this simple example is both understandable and readable. However, when you have multiple `>>=` operators, would the `where` clause be a better approach? For instance: `chargeAccount >>= reserveProduct =>> finaliseTransaction` where each function is defined in the `where` clause.

Comment: In general, yes, I think that's a good idea. However, in this case I don't think that a where clause defining `numLines = length . lines` is any clearer than inlining `length . lines` which is already a succinct description of what this function does.